# Inheritance Issue: Overridden Method in Derived Class Calls Base Class Method

Tags: angular, typescript

I am encountering an issue with method overriding in an Angular application using TypeScript. I have a base component class (BaseComponent) with a method (updateMetaData) that I am trying to override in a derived class (HomeComponent). Despite using the override keyword, the base class method is still being called.

BaseComponent (the base class):

```
export class BaseComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
 // ... 

    ngOnInit() {
        this.updateMetaData();
    }

    protected updateMetaData(): void {
        console.log("BaseComponent updateMetaData");

    }

    // ... 
}
```

HomeComponent (the derived class):

```
export class HomeComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit {

    override ngOnInit(): void {
        this.updateMetaData();
    }

    override updateMetaData(): void {
        console.log("HomeComponent updateMetaData");

    }

    // ... 
}
```

The expectation is that when HomeComponent is used, its updateMetaData method should be called. However, what happens is that both the updateMetaData method of HomeComponent and BaseComponent are executed.

Here's what I've tried/verified:

Ensured that there are no calls to super.updateMetaData() in HomeComponent.
Checked for any indirect calls to updateMetaData in other methods.
Verified that ngOnInit in HomeComponent does not call super.ngOnInit().
I am puzzled as to why the base class method is still being invoked. Is there something I am missing in the way Angular handles overridden methods? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "*both the updateMetaData method of HomeComponent and BaseComponent are executed.*" - put a `debugger` or `console.trace()` statement in its code to find where it is being called from. But without a [mcve] we cannot help you

Comment: I would say you have both instance of home component and instance base component rendered in your applications and therefore you are getting calls of all of the methods

Comment: It was a pretty silly problem, but it was hard to figure out.  lol
There was a component inside the home component template and this component also derives from the base component.